# How to see/verify encrypted ebs volume data?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2

I have used non-default kms keys to encrypt the ebs volumes attached to my mongodb ec2 instance including the root volume. My java application running on a separate ec2 instance is able to access unencrypted data from my mongodb server although the role assigned to it doesn't have access to the key I used to encrypt my volumes.
My understanding is that only the users or services which have access to the encryption keys should get the unencrypted data. Is this correct? If not then please explain it a bit.

How can I see or verify that my data is getting encrypted (other than seeing that my volume is encrypted on aws console) and I how can I control who sees them in unencrypted form?

Comment: So your MongoDB server has access to the KMS key, and the encrypted EBS volume, correct? And you are expecting your Java app to magically be blocked from querying MongoDB because it doesn't have access to the KMS key that the MongoDB server is using behind the scenes to access an EBS volume?

Comment: Yes this is what I was expecting more or less. My understanding might be completely wrong please correct me if possible. What I am trying to achieve is encrypted my data at rest residing on the ebs volumes and control who can access them unencrypted. If you know any way to achieve this on aws please suggest.

Comment: EBS encryption only deals with encryption at rest. Once your MongoDB server has access to the data (due to running on an EC2 server that has access to it) then the data gets loaded in the database, thus it's not "at rest" anymore. Anything that accesses the MongoDB server and queries the data will be completely unrestricted by the EBS encryption. MongoDB doesn't somehow magically know that it is reading data from an encrypted EBS volume and require clients to send a KMS key for a query.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought as databases ultimately store their data on some disk only so encrypting the disk should be enough. After reading a bit I got to know that it is data in use and not data at rest ( you can correct me again).

Answer (score -2):

To view status checks in the console

Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

In the navigation pane, choose Volumes.

On the EBS Volumes page, use the Volume Status column lists the operational status of each volume.

To view an individual volume's status, select the volume, and choose Status Checks.

```
                        Viewing EBS volume status
```

If you have a volume with a failed status check (status is impaired), see Working with an Impaired Volume.

Comment: How does this answer the question?